# What is the latency from hibernated state to a request can be accepted on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, latency

AWS supports [hibernation of instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Hibernate.html) to EBS storage.  From the hibernated state, they can be resumed and continue execution.

How useful hibernation is compared to starting a new instance is crucially linked to startup time of a fresh instance vs how long it takes for a hibernated instance to continue running, specifically how long it takes to be able to accept and process network requests.

How long does this take?

Comment: Try it and find out! It's a normal Operating System hibernation, so it will probably depending upon the size of RAM. Let us know what you find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time taken for hibernated instance to resume depends on the size of the RAM. If you are using instances with low to medium memory, your instances should resume pretty quickly.

However, that should not be the only consideration because Hibernation allows you to resume the instance (with the applications) from the saved state. If your instance on a fresh start requires bootstrapping time, in that case, Hibernation will be much more beneficial for you.

Based on the results mentioned in AWS Blog of "[How Backbase How Backbase Leveraged EC2 Hibernation to Reduce Compute Spending by 30%](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/startups/how-backbase-used-ec2-to-reduce-computing-costs/)", Backbase is able to resume instances within 30 seconds.